# Swift Spritekit setvalue

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In swift with spritekit I want to set a variable of a sprite so I tried to say

```
p.setValue(value: (String(c)), forKey: "co")
```

But this gives an error.

So the main question is:

How can i set a key value pair in a sprite to a string
 as a key and an int/string as a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setValue(_:forKey:)` and related methods aren't for associating arbitrary key/value data with an object. They're part of Key-Value Coding, a Cocoa feature that does all sorts of handy things — but unless a class does something special with KVC, all `setValue(_:forKey:)` does is let you set one of that class's declared properties using a string instead of by directly accessing a property. In other words, the two lines below are equivalent:

```
node.name = "foo"
node.setValue("foo", forKey: "name")
```

If you want to associate arbitrary key-value pairs with your sprites—which can be a great way to keep track of entities in your game—use the [`userData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData) property.

Answer (score 1):

To use `setValue:forKey:` you need to have (a) a valid key, and (b) a value of the correct type for that key. For example:

```
mySprite.setValue(UIColor.redColor(), forKey: "co")  // error, "co" isn't a valid key
mySprite.setValue("red", forKey: "color")            // error, "color" needs a UIColor value
mySprite.setValue(UIColor.redColor(), forKey: "color")   // works!
```

What value and key are you actually using?